# $argv in a class

Tags: php, class, argv

I'm using `exec()` to exec a file but the file is in a class, I read more about argv  but it was confusing. I need to get it to work inside a class.

It says:

> Please note that, $argv and $argc need to be declared global, while trying to access within a class method

<sub>on php.net</sub>

Comment: And what the goal? Arguments are for console execution.

Answer (score 27):

That means argc/argv aren't superglobals - they're only visible at the top-level context of PHP scripts, so...

```
<?php

$x = $argv[1]; // works

class foo {
   function bar() {
       echo $argv[1]; // undefined
   }
   function baz() {
       global $argv;
       echo $argv[1]; // works
   }
}
```

Comment: This can be done by using `$GLOBALS['argv']...` as well. In case copying a variable to your current scope or trying to make them superglobal is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

i add argv as arguments to the class constructor

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $args;

    public function __construct($args) 
    {
        $this->args = $args;
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        $this->args[1]; //access args using $this->args
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass($args);
```